# With sed what is difference between sed -n '1,2p;3q' and sed -n '1,2p;2q'

Tags: sed

Is there any difference between `sed -n '1,2p;3q'` and `sed -n '1,2p;2q'`

I have  a file with 3 lines:

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
#comment 3
```

And I couldn't notice any difference. Both printed out the first two lines only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK they are functionally equivalent. There would be a difference if you did **not** use the `-n` option, as noted in the manual (emphasis mine):

```
       q [exit-code]
              Immediately quit the sed  script  without  processing  any  more
              input,  except  that  if  auto-print is not disabled the current
              pattern space will be printed.  The exit code argument is a  GNU
              extension.
```

So without the `-n`

```
$ sed  '1,2p;2q' file
#comment 1
#comment 1
#comment 2
#comment 2
```

but

```
$ sed  '1,2p;3q' file
#comment 1
#comment 1
#comment 2
#comment 2
#comment 3
```